# PHP, enable ZTS, Pthreads

Tags: php, pthreads, zts

I need ZTS to be enabled in php. So I recompiled php from source with '--enable-maintainer-zts' option. Now I have:
"php -v"

```
PHP 7.0.11 (cli) (built: Oct  3 2016 12:19:10) ( ZTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

"php -i"

```
Thread Safety => enabled
```

Now I am trying to do 
"sudo pecl install pthreads" which answers me

```
checking whether to enable pthreads... yes, shared
checking whether to enable AddressSanitizer for pthreads... no
checking whether to enable dmalloc for pthreads... no
checking for ZTS... configure: error: pthreads requires ZTS, please re-compile PHP with ZTS enabled
ERROR: `/var/tmp/pthreads/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config' failed
```

Please, help me. What's wrong?

CentOS 7.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Install PHP-Zts manually on the Centos 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59601583/how-to-install-php-zts-manually-on-the-centos-7)

Comment: The OP is probably asking why the configure script says "no ZTS KTHXBYE" even though PHP says "Thread Safety => enabled".

Answer (score 3):

Install all the dependencies for compiling php, a reference to that for fedora/cent os is [here](https://coderwall.com/p/ggmpfa/php-configuration-error-and-solutions-in-rpm)

Then this is the script i used just make a file php-zts-installer.sh extention and run it as superuser `sudo ./php-zts-installer.sh`

content of php-zts-install.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p /etc/php7
mkdir -p /etc/php7/cli

git clone https://github.com/php/php-src.git -b PHP-7.0.17 --depth=1
cd php-src/ext
git clone https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads -b master pthreads

cd ..

./buildconf --force

./configure --prefix=/etc/php7 --with-bz2 --with-zlib --enable-zip --disable-cgi \
    --enable-soap --enable-intl --with-mcrypt --with-openssl --with-readline --with-curl \
    --enable-ftp --enable-mysqlnd --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
    --enable-sockets --enable-pcntl --with-pspell --with-enchant --with-gettext \
    --with-gd --enable-exif --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --with-freetype-dir --with-xsl \
    --enable-bcmath --enable-mbstring --enable-calendar --enable-simplexml --enable-json \
    --enable-hash --enable-session --enable-xml --enable-wddx --enable-opcache \
    --with-pcre-regex --with-config-file-path=/etc/php7/cli \
    --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php7/etc --enable-cli --enable-maintainer-zts \
    --with-tsrm-pthreads --enable-debug --enable-fpm \
    --with-fpm-user=www-data --with-fpm-group=www-data

make && make install

chmod o+x /etc/php7/bin/phpize
chmod o+x /etc/php7/bin/php-config

cd ext/pthreads*
/etc/php7/bin/phpize

./configure --prefix=/etc/php7 --with-libdir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-pthreads=shared --with-php-config=/etc/php7/bin/php-config

make && make install

cd ../../
cp -r php.ini-development /etc/php7/cli/php.ini

cp php.ini-development /etc/php7/cli/php-cli.ini
echo "extension=pthreads.so" > /etc/php7/cli/php-cli.ini
echo "zend_extension=opcache.so" >> /etc/php7/cli/php.ini

ln --symbolic /etc/php7/bin/php /usr/bin/php

export USE_ZEND_ALLOC=0
```