# Can not install pthreads

Tags: php, ubuntu, pthreads, php-7, zts

I am trying to install pthreads on to a local ubuntu environment. When I attempt to install the extension using pecl:

```
pecl install pthreads
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/pthreads/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config' failed

But I have installed:

```
vagrant@freid:/$ php7.0-zts -v
PHP 7.0.5-4+donate.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( ZTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

Here's my full output;

```
downloading pthreads-3.1.6.tgz ...
Starting to download pthreads-3.1.6.tgz (80,932 bytes)
...................done: 80,932 bytes
28 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20151012
Zend Module Api No:      20151012
Zend Extension Api No:   320151012
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root5N00Nz/pthreads-3.1.6
running: /tmp/pear/temp/pthreads/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php/20151012
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php/20151012
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether to enable pthreads... yes, shared
checking whether to enable AddressSanitizer for pthreads... no
checking whether to enable dmalloc for pthreads... no
checking for ZTS... configure: error: pthreads requires ZTS, please re-compile PHP with ZTS enabled
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/pthreads/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config' failed
```

Comment: `error: pthreads requires ZTS, please re-compile PHP with ZTS enabled ` What's the question?

Comment: Look there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782860/how-to-install-php-pthreads-extension-on-ubuntu

Comment: But I have php7.0-zts already installed

Comment: Think i'm experiencing the same problem that this guy is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39829944/php-enable-zts-pthreads

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39829944/php-enable-zts-pthreads This worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install php with thread safety enabled.
This string tells you about it:

```
checking for ZTS... configure: error: pthreads requires ZTS, please re-compile PHP with ZTS enabled
```

You have another PHP (without zts) that installed in your system. This php installation is used when you try to install pthreads.

Comment: I can see the issue, but what is the solution?

Comment: You need to remove one of the PHP installations. Or setup alternatives in your OS.